# FormatException in Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#

I am currently using a method to toggle a menu in my console which returns a `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

When a string is in-putted on debug, it gives me this error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

I have tried researching this error on MSDN but cannot work out how to add a format to it. Could someone please maybe give me a link to a simple fix? Thank-you.

Comment: What is the input of `Console.ReadLine()` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Looks like your `Convert.ToInt32` method throws this exception as far as I see.

Comment: Any String, e.g.  sdasds would return this error.

Comment: _Any_ string? So, how do you think you parse `sdasds` string to integer?

Comment: 'Convert.ToInt32(choice);'       ? (choice being the stored input variable)

Comment: I think, you need something like this `int choice = 0; int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);`

Comment: The switch is irrelevant, the exception occurs in `Convert.ToInt32()` .

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that your user input is an integer, you can use [Int32.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. Clearly you can't convert `sdasds` to an int.

Check that it's an `int`, and if it isn't, keep prompting the user:

```
int choice = 0;
while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter a valid integer");
}
```

Then use `choice` in your `switch` block:

```
switch (choice)
{
     case 1:
        addcourse();
     break;
// etc...
```

Comment: Happy to help - if this answers your question then feel free mark it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).